# QT + Net Framework

Tags: .net, qt

В QT пока мягко говоря не силён, хочу попробовать сделать небольшую утилитку, но возник вопрос , можно ли использовать [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) из NetFramework в QT, просто нужно использовать не только OnChanged и OnRenamed, а все так-же Created и Deleted.

Comment: Вы хотите скрестить ужа с ежом. Вполне возможно, что такие мутанты существуют, но насколько я понимаю лучше всего пользоваться тем, что есть в Qt.

Comment: QFileSystemWatcher ничего по сути не даёт, способ получать OnChanged и OnRenamed у меня есть и сейчас, хотелось бы получить больше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetFramework это виртуальная машина, поэтому в одном exe скрестить нельзя, для скрещивания надо написать на C# dll и использовать её из Qt

Я много помучился с этим QFileSystemWatcher на сетевых устройствах, советую сразу попробовать, на NFS железно не будет работать, может только polling

Comment: у меня всё локально, ну точнее там SAN, но по сути устройство блочное и выглядит для системы как обычный диск